# TFS: How to get the filename or filepath of files associated with the work item

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs, tfs-workitem

So I managed to get the commit ID of each file (using git) and I want to check if each file is related to a work item in my repository in TFS. I'm stuck here. I was able to access it remotely and get a collection of work items, but I need to query it somehow so that I can find any work items related to a (edited) file. Nothing in the work items fields seem to be helpful either...

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using?

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT 14.114.26403.0

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT I used HttpClient and stored client.GetStringAsync(uri) as a string and tried converting it to json, but I was unable. What rest api did you use?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [TFS rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/git/commits/get%20commits?view=vsts-rest-4.1) to achieve your requirement. The following example retrieves git commits for a project with workitems:

```
Get https://{accountName}.visualstudio.com/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/commits?searchCriteria.includeWorkItems=true&api-version=4.1
```

The response of API is as below:

[image]

If you don't know the `repositoryId`, you could list it with the api below:

```
GET https://{accountName}.visualstudio.com/{project}/_apis/git/repositories?api-version=4.1
```